# declaring a function with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

First of all, im a c++ noob! Ok with that being said, i need to declare a function that initializes a grid. The function takes an array of int as the input and needs to return an array of `int`. I have:

```
array<int> InitializeGrid (array<int>)
{
    const int NB_ROWS = 10;
    const int NB_COLUMN = 10;
    const int WATER = 0;

    int grid[NB_ROWS][NB_COLONN];


    for (int i = 0; i < NB_ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NB_COLONN; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = WATER;
            cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return ??
}
```

Comment: `array<int>` doesn't look valid, assuming it is `std::array`. Also what is the array you are returning supposed to include?

Comment: And your question is - what?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return anything if you pass the array by reference:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

static const int NB_ROWS = 10;
static const int NB_COLUMN = 10;
static const int WATER = 0;

void InitializeGrid (std::array<std::array<int, NB_COLUMN>, NB_ROWS> &grid)
{
    for (auto &row : grid)
    {
        for (auto &col : row)
        {
            col = WATER;
            std::cout << col << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, NB_COLUMN>, NB_ROWS> grid;
    InitializeGrid(grid);
}
```

btw, if your `WATER` is `0` it is sufficive to write

```
std::array<std::array<int, NB_COLUMN>, NB_ROWS> grid{};
```

to initialize all elements to zero.